# how to setup multiple paths in user environmental variables in windows 10

Tags: node.js, react-native, windows-10, environment-variables

I want to set up multiple paths in the user environmental variables in windows 10. but can only set a single path, how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Environmental variable for react native ?

Comment: I'm getting started with react-native but having issues with user environmental variables. Because I have to specify multiple var but only able to add a single variable at a time, when I install node.js then it's path overrides the previously written path such as react-native-cli path

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add user defined environment variable then use react-native-config library. So in short if there are variables defined in .env file then you can use it anywhere in the react-native app like below:-

.env file

> API_URL = "https://baseurl/endpoint"

//To use the above environment variable

> import config react-native-config
>
> function apiCall() {   axios(config) }

With the help of react-native-config you can use environment variable in native code also and vise-versa.

For better use define .env.staging file. By default config lib finds .env file. To run the application with .env.staging file see below command.

> $ ENVFILE=.env.staging react-native run-ios           # bash
>
> $ SET ENVFILE=.env.staging && react-native run-ios    # windows
>
> $ env:ENVFILE=".env.staging"; react-native run-ios    # powershell

For more information checkout :- https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Happy coding mate :)

Comment: not this, i want to add it in windows user environmental variables

Answer (score 0):

to add multiple paths for a single environment variable, list them all with a semicolon(";") in between like that:
**C:\Cpp_Headers\pybind11;C:\Cpp_Headers\cpython\Include;C:\Users\admin\Cpp_Headers\cpython\PC**
(and so forth). From this input Windows will automatically recognize multiple definitions.